# integration of flex/ssrs (Flex based UI for reports created in SSRS)

Tags: .net, apache-flex, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008

We have an application which is created in **asp.net/flex** front end, ms **sql/ssas** as data source.

We are in phase of creating a new reporting module. so for consistency of graphs and ui we want to use flex as front end and SSAS as backend for reporting module.

My understanding is:

*Flex based UI (reports/parameters)

SSRS Reports (standard or fixed/ custom) should be shown inside an iframe asp.net page to pass the paremeters to reportviewer control.*

We need to finilize the approach, it could be any third party component (shold be comparable to ssrs) or the approach i suggested above is okay.

*Please share your views...*

Comment: Hi Lalit, I was wondering if you have found any solution for your question yet. I have the same problem and need to use my SSRS reports inside the Flex. Would you please update your question if you have any answer for it?

Comment: we used aspx pages for both parameters and report.

Comment: Hey Lalit, I did create the aspx pages, but when I run it I get 401:Unauthorized error. I'm thinking that it should be something that I need to change in the Report Server configuration, but I don't know what and how! Do you have any suggestion? Thank you.